# Show div using Angular ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show, angularjs-ng-show

I'm havings some problems with `ng-show` and `$pristine`.

Here is the code ([also on CodePen](http://codepen.io/edenlyriene/pen/wGvKKG)):

```
<blockquote ng-show="!comment.author.$pristine && !comment.rating.$pristine && !comment.comment.$pristine">
    <p>{{comment.rating}} Stars</p>
    <p>{{comment.comment}}</p>
    <footer>{{comment.author}}
</blockqoute>
```

When every field on the form has been filled, I want to show the div that contains my duplicate, but I want it to be hidden while some are still empty.

I tried to to use

```
!comment.[index].$pristine && ....
```

so when every field has been filled, the blockquote would become visible, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey the way you are going the main problem will be that when the user will be filling any random data in the last text box, the moment he fills a letter the div will be visible to him - despite whatever improvements you make to the code.

What I'll suggest is - make use of `ng-show="whatever"` for that section that you want to show after the data has been filled.

In the beginning where your controller starts make it false `$scope.whatever = false;` and now it wont be visible to the user; when the user has filled all the text boxes call a trigger and check if the data is valid or not and then `$scope.whatever=true;` - Now your section will be visible.

To call the trigger you can do various things
- you can make use of `ng-change` on the last textbox and there check values of all textboxes using their specific model name, I hope you know that.

Let me know if you want further clarification on this.

Comment: thank you for your explanation! After I tried your method, the result was better than what I hope in the top

Comment: May I know why did you delete the recent question?

Comment: It was very immature of me and was a low quality question.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I accept your claim and I am sorry for the same. Can you please give me the name of the other guy? I should not have done that but I can compensate for the same.

Comment: @GandalftheWhite Not sure buddy, in my answer, there *was* a comment, now gone, by someone named starting with `A`. Anyway, at least you understood what you caused. Thanks for that. `:)`

Comment: @GandalftheWhite Tamil payyanaa nee? `:)`

Comment: No Mate, let's delete the comments now ;)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can specify `ng-hide` as a className to hide it by default.

```
<blockquote ng-show="whatever" class="ng-hide"
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
<blockquote ng-show="!comment.author.$pristine && !comment.rating.$pristine && !comment.comment.$pristine">
                          <p>{{comment.rating}} Stars</p>
                          <p>{{comment.comment}}</p>
                          <footer>{{comment.author}}
                    </blockqoute>
```

To this

```
<blockquote ng-show="!commentForm.author.$pristine && !commentForm.comment.$pristine">
                              <p>{{comment.rating}} Stars</p>
                              <p>{{comment.comment}}</p>
                              <footer>{{comment.author}}, {{comment.date | date}}</footer>
                        </blockqoute>
```

Notice I'm using the form to check for the form properties, not the scope properties. Just change `comment` to `commentForm` (which is your form's name).

- **[More info about form controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController)**
- **[Working codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqObxa)**

Comment: @GáborCsikós it's working in the codepen I made. Check that you set a form name and use that name in the ng-show, or make a codepen to see what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would bind values of the form input to some variables in the controller, and on their `ng-change="controller.validate()"` run a validate code, so you can check if fields are not empty and input is correct and after that set `isBlockquoteVisible` variable, that would be in `<blockquote ng-show="{{controller.isBlockquoteVisible}}" ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
<blockquote ng-hide="comment.author.$pristine && comment.rating.$pristine && comment.comment.$pristine">
   <p ng-show="!comment.rating.$pristine">{{comment.rating}} Stars</p>
   <p ng-show="!comment.comment.$pristine">{{comment.comment}}</p>
   <footer ng-show="!comment.author.$pristine">{{comment.author}}</footer>
</blockquote>
```